# Split Columns with Condition in Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a "Code" and "Amount column. I need to split both of them into three different columns based on the condition. Example:

| Code | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | $40.00 |
| 1 | $20.00 |

Condition: First $5.00 goes to Code1, $10.00 goes to Code2 and

Output:

| Code | Amount | Code1 | Amount1 | Code2 | Amount2 | Code3 | Amount3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $40.00 | 1.1 | $5.00 | 1.2 | $10.00 | 1.3 | $25.00 |
| 1 | $20.00 | 1.1 | $5.00 | 1.2 | $10.00 | 1.3 | $5.00 |

I tried apply function but I am not getting any desired results.

Comment: Is `Code4` and `Amount4` supposed to be in the missing headers? What is the logic behind `Code1` to `Code4` and `Amount1` to `Amount4`?

Comment: Yes, the last two columns could be named Code 4 and Amount 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop:

```
subamounts = [5, 10, 1000]

l = [df]
remainder = df['Amount']
for i, x in enumerate(subamounts, start=1):
    remainder = remainder.sub(x)
    l.append(pd.DataFrame({f'Code{i}': df['Code'].astype(str).add(f'.{i}'),
                           f'Amount {i}': x+remainder.clip(upper=0)
                          }))
    remainder = remainder.clip(lower=0)

out = pd.concat(l, axis=1)
```

Output (with more examples):

```
   Code  Amount Code1  Amount 1 Code2  Amount 2 Code3  Amount 3
0     1    40.0   1.1       5.0   1.2      10.0   1.3      25.0
1     1    20.0   1.1       5.0   1.2      10.0   1.3       5.0
2     1     7.0   1.1       5.0   1.2       2.0   1.3       0.0
3     1     3.0   1.1       3.0   1.2       0.0   1.3       0.0
```